# How to create table in Postgressql in pascal case

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, .net-core, identity

I try to use Postgressql with IdentityUser in c# .netcore and when i create table in Postgressql i use like this sql for create table

```
 CREATE TABLE AspNetUsers(
    Id Varchar(450) NOT NULL,
    AccessFailedCount int NOT NULL,
    ConcurrencyStamp Text NULL,
    Email Varchar(256) NULL,
    EmailConfirmed Boolean NOT NULL,
    LockoutEnabled Boolean NOT NULL,
    LockoutEnd Timestamp(6) WITH TIME ZONE NULL,
    NormalizedEmail Varchar(256) NULL,
    NormalizedUserName Varchar(256) NULL,
    PasswordHash Text NULL,
    PhoneNumber Text NULL,
    PhoneNumberConfirmed Boolean NOT NULL,
    SecurityStamp Text NULL,
    TwoFactorEnabled Boolean NOT NULL,
    UserName Varchar(256) NULL
);
```

It create table show same this image

[image]

It not work with Microsoft AspNetCore Identity and when i handle manual to Postgressql db to this image

[image]

It work done have no error.

Surely no one want to manual change to pascal case .How can i create database in pascal case ?

**I use PostgreSQL on windowos

postgresql-10.1-3-windows-x64

pgadmin4 v.2.0

Flask Version0.11.1

Comment: Are you asking because your scaffolded data model in c# isn't in the case you want, (all your c# class names and properties are lowercase and you want PascalCase) or because you don't like how it looks in your database query tool?

Comment: Put the column and table names in double quotes. But then you have to always do that since the default is to lowercase everything.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thank it work

Comment: @CaiusJard No when I scaffold i will set python case in database but i need pascal case  cus when i use UserManager<IdentityUser> or  SignInManager<IdentityUser> from lib Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity  it can't see field in lowercase.I setup from this https://medium.com/@RobertKhou/asp-net-core-mvc-identity-using-postgresql-database-bc52255f67c4  .